# JavaScript addEventListener() external function triggering without the event

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm drawing a grid of boxes, want to be able to click on each box and send notification with its ID to server using SocketIO

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="2" class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>

let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
    box.addEventListener('click', function()  {
        id = box.id

        //Send socketio message to server
        socket.emit('box_event_client', {data: id});
    });
});
```

This works, I can click each box and event is sent to server, but apparently this does not allow the even listener to be removed, as per
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeeventlistener.asp

*Note: To remove event handlers, the function specified with the addEventListener() method must be an external function,
 Anonymous functions, like "element.removeEventListener("event", function(){ myScript });" will not work.*

So I changed to this

```
Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
    box.addEventListener('click', addEL(box.id));
});

function addEL(boxID) {
    console.log("Box clicked: " + boxID)

    //Send socketio message to server
    socket.emit('box', {data: boxID});
}
```

Now as soon page is loaded into browser all boxes in grid are automatically 'clicked' and events sent to server.

Can anyone help understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone help understand why this is happening?

```
Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
    box.addEventListener('click', addEL(box.id));
});
```

`addEL(box.id)` is **function call** therefore its taking id and executing it on each box's click listener attachment

***Solution:***

`AddEventListener` expects the event name and the `callback function name` or the `function` itself(inline function)

Just give the function name in the parameter.

```
Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
    box.addEventListener('click', addEL);
});
```

Access the id of the box from event object like  `event.currentTarget.id`

```
function addEL(event) {
    let boxId=event.currentTarget.id
    console.log("Box clicked: " + boxId)
    //Send socketio message to server
    socket.emit('box', {data: boxId});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this let me do what I wanted.

Comment: How does that `addEventListener` second parameter `event` object is passed to the `addEl()` function when you do not explicitly do so - `box.addEventListener('click', addEL);` I am so curious

Comment: @MaksimDimitrov It's automatically passed by `addEventListener()`.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
box.addEventListener('click', addEL(box.id));
```

to

```
box.addEventListener('click', function() { addEL(box.id) });
```

or simplier (be sure you can use ES6 here)

```
box.addEventListener('click', () => addEL(box.id));
```

or

```
box.addEventListener('click', addEL.bind(null, box.id));
```

it's because you use the result of the function, not the function itself

UPD: to be able to delete handler declare the function like `var adder = addEL.bind(null, box.id)` and use `box.addEventListener('click', adder);`

also there can be an array of such functions like `adders.push(addEL.bind(null, box.id))`, `box.addEventListener('click', adders[i]);`

Comment: And how will that solve `but apparently this does not allow the even listener to be removed`?

Comment: didn't notice this notice. wrote UPD to the answer

Answer (score 1):

The code `box.addEventListener('click', addEL(box.id));` calls `addEL(box.id)` and passes the result of that call to the second argument of `addEventListener`, that's why `addEL` is called directly without any event.

if you want to be able to remove the listener then you need to write it that way:

```
Array.from(boxes, function(box) {
    let clickCallback = function()  {
        id = box.id

        //Send socketio message to server
        socket.emit('box_event_client', {data: id});
    }

    box.addEventListener('click', clickCallback);

    // you can remove the listener within the scope where clickCallback is defined
    // box.removeEventListener('click', clickCallback);
});
```